# Have one wt server per machine and have multiple processes post pages to it

Tags: wt

Is this possible?

Right now I have one wt server being launcher per application instance, but I've been told they would like there to be one wt server per machine (not matter how many application instances are launched).

There will only be a maximum of 3 applications per machine, but this requires 3 different ports to be opened for communication (one per application).

How can this be done?

My boss said something about using JSON to send data...??

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how I should understand your question - do you want to deploy three applications, all listening at port 80, in three different URLs, or do you want to have one process listening on three different ports?

The former can be done by invoking WServer::addEntryPoint() multiple times. See examples/simplechat/simpleChat.C, but then with multiple calls to addEntryPoint() for type Wt::Application.

The latter can be done by instantiating multiple WServer objects, each with their own configuration. See examples/feature/multiple_servers.